# About the convergence of a real series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series, $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\log n)^p}$ where $p>0$ converge of diverge? Which test is suitable? Can we use comparison test?

Comment: For $p=1$ You can compare the terms to the harmonic series. Since $log(n)<n$, $\frac{1}{log(n)}>\frac{1}{n}$ and the series is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that for all $p>0$, $\;(\log n)^p =o(n)$, hence 
$$\frac1n=o\biggl(\frac1{(\log n)^p}\biggr),$$
so sinec the former diverges, the latter diverges too.

Comment: What does it mean $(\log n)^p =o(n)$?

Comment: That' *Landau's notation* to say that $\;\dfrac{(\log n)^p}n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: But, how do we prove this limit?

Comment: Just check the log of this fraction: $\;p\log(\log n)-\log n=-\log n\biggl(1-p\dfrac{\log(\log n)}{\log n}\biggr)\to -\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

We shall try the *$\sum 2^ka_{2^k}$ test*.

We have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^ka_{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k}{\big(\log(2^k))\big)^p}
=\frac{1}{(\log 2)^p}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k^p}.
$$
The last sum is clearly divergent. (Use for example the ratio test.) Hence the original sum is also divergent.